# (Smirnov 1939) Paper: On the estimation of the discrepancy between empirical curves of distribution for two independent samples.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, asymptotics

Does anyone have an english copy of this paper and/or any other reference where the results from this paper are explained? Unable to find it after searching for many days. Please let me know if you need any further information.

The full citation is below:

1) Smirnov, N. V. (1939). On the estimation of the discrepancy between empirical curves of distribution for two independent samples. Bull. Math. Univ. Moscou, 2(2).

Two papers with important results are also not found. Please post links to the paper or references that explain it in English.

2) Smirnov, N. V. (1939). Ob uklonenijah empiricheskoi krivoi raspredelenija. Recueil Mathematique (Matematiceskii Sbornik), N.S. Vol. 6(48), pp. 3-26.

3) Smirnov, N. V. E. (1944). Approximate laws of distribution of random variables from empirical data. Uspekhi Matematicheskikh Nauk, (10), 179-206.

Comment: Not quite what you asked for, but you have a review on AMS: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2062

Comment: I can send you a pdf of the review. It is very short, though.